# Month Name in another Language - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, date, translate

Hi all I need to display the **current month** name and to do that I am using `Date()` and `formatted(.dateTime.month(.wide))`

This way I can get the full name of the **current month**.

My problem is that the language in which I display it (even on the real device) is in English and I would need to display it in Italian as the whole app will be in Italian

A long time ago I didn't need to do any operations for automatic translation but now also on my device (iphone 13 pro max) I continue to view it in English

Is there something I forgot to do? Can you help me ?

```
var date: Date = Date()
date.formatted(.dateTime.month(.wide))
// Return January instead Gennaio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a `locale` modifier

```
Text(date.formatted(.dateTime
                    .month(.wide)
                    .locale(.init(identifier: "it_IT"))))
```

Comment: ah ok ... i have to force the code so .. i haven't forgotten some xcode settings